# Use literal style for just multiline strings in ruamel.yaml

Tags: python, ruamel.yaml

I would like to have a custom `ruamel.yaml` dumper that uses Literal style for all multiline strings and the default style otherwise. For example:

```py
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

data = {"a": "hello", "b": "hello\nthere\nworld"}

print("Default style")
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)

print()
print("style='|'")
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.default_style = "|"
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

This produces:

```
Default style
a: hello
b: "hello\nthere\nworld"

style='|'
"a": |-
  hello
"b": |-
  hello
  there
  world
```

My desired output is:

```
a: hello
b: |-
  hello
  there
  world
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to achieve what you want. If you have control over building up the
data structure, it is often easiest to add a `LiteralScalarString` if appropriate:

```py
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

def lim(s):  # literal if multi-line
    if '\n' in s:
        return ruamel.yaml.scalarstring.LiteralScalarString(s)
    return s

data = {'a': lim('hello'), 'b': lim('hello\nthere\nworld')}

    
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
a: hello
b: |-
  hello
  there
  world
```

This gives you easy fine control over what gets dumped as literal style.

If you don't add all the data individually (but e.g. read them from a JSON file), you
can walk over your data structure after it is fully constructed and update it in place:

```py
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

def tmtl(d):
    """translate multi-line to literal,
       only acts on dict values and sequence items, not on keys
    """
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        for k, v in d.items():
            if isinstance(v, str) and '\n' in v:
                d[k] = ruamel.yaml.scalarstring.LiteralScalarString(v)
            else:
                tmtl(v)
    elif isinstance(d, list):
        for idx, item in enumerate(d):
            if isinstance(item, str) and '\n' in item:
                d[idx] = ruamel.yaml.scalarstring.LiteralScalarString(item)

data = {'a': 'hello', 'b': 'hello\nthere\nworld'}
tmtl(data)
    
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
a: hello
b: |-
  hello
  there
  world
```

If you cannot update your `data`, you could rewrite `tmtl` in the program above
so it builds a new data structure and returns that, but at that point it is IMO
easier to change the representer:

```py
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

CKS = ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedKeySeq  # so you can have sequences as keys in a mapping

class MyRepresenter(ruamel.yaml.representer.RoundTripRepresenter):
    def represent_str(self, s):
        if '\n' in s:
            return self.represent_scalar('tag:yaml.org,2002:str', s, style='|')
        return self.represent_scalar('tag:yaml.org,2002:str', s)

MyRepresenter.add_representer(str, MyRepresenter.represent_str)

data = {'a': 'hello', 'b': 'hello\nthere\nworld', CKS((1, 2)): ['nested works\nas well\n\n']}
    
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.Representer = MyRepresenter
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
a: hello
b: |-
  hello
  there
  world
[1, 2]:
- |+
  nested works
  as well

...
```

As you can see the trailing newlines of the final literal style scalar automatically
causes the chomping indicator to change from strip (`-`) to keep (`+`) and the
explicit document end marker (`...`) to appear.

Comment: BTW, I had already been gotten to the idea of the `tmtl` data-fixer but the conditional representer for `str` seems nicer. Putting examples like these in the docs of customization approaches would be great.

Comment: I have planned to do a review of the docs after releasing 0.18. Going over all my answers here on SO, both updating them to reflect the changes and selecting some of them as workflow examples for the documentation. Now I only have to find the time to work on all that ...